# PHP Text area foreach line

Tags: php, loops, foreach, textarea, do-while

Im trying to code a php script that will loop a process for each line in a Textarea post. I was wondering if someone can post an example.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You might have to use \r\n instead of just \n for textarea (I remember figuring it out for quite a while)

Comment: was using "\n" to no avail... "\r\n" worked for me using explode()..thanks!

Answer (score 13):

```
foreach(explode("\n", $text) as $line) {
    // do something
}
```

See the manual page on [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

Comment: Browsers can be funny about what chars they use to separate lines in a textarea -- i've seen a lot that just use `\x0d`, while some others might use `\x0d\x0a`.  I've never seen one yet that just uses `\x0a`, but i guess it's possible.  May also depend on the textarea's settings, and whether soft wrapping is enabled.